# wordpress wp_ajax returning 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Error returned in browser console: 400 bad request

I traced the error to this part in the admin-ajax.php file by changing the response value from 0 to 1:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
// If no action is registered, return a Bad Request response.
if ( ! has_action( "wp_ajax_{$action}" ) ) {
    wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

I tried everything, but unfortunately I didn't understand what this login really means and how it works.

I saw some people having a problem with the host, in my case I'm using hostinger. (I don't think this is relevant but here it is.)

Javascript

```
function formVali﻿﻿﻿dation() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = document.forms["contactForm"]["name"].value;
  var email = document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;
  var subject = docu﻿ment.forms["contactForm"]["subject"].value;
  var message = document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
  var errorMessage="<span class='error'>All fields are required.</span>";
  var regEx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

     if (name.trim() == "" ||email.trim() == "" || subject.trim() == "" || message.trim() == "") {
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = errorMessage;
         return false;
       }
   if (!regEx.test(email)) {
       var errorMessage="<span class='error'>Invalid email.</span>";
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = errorMessage;
        return false;
      }
  processContactSubmit();﻿
  return true;
}

function processContactSubmit() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=process_contact_form");
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            var myForm = document.getElem﻿entById("contactForm");
            var formData = new FormData(contactForm);
            request.send(formData);}
```

functions.php ﻿

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form');
add_act﻿ion﻿('wp_ajax_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form'); //Retirar essa parte para error no console, no contrario ira aparecer no navegador o numero 0.

function process_contact_form() {
    $to = "Recipient﻿ Email Address";
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $headers = "Testing";
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $attachments = "";
    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject﻿, $message, $headers, $attachments);
    if (! $sent) {
        echo "<span class='error'>Problem in sending mail.</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<sp﻿an class='success'>Hi, thank you for the message.</span>";
    }
    wp_﻿di﻿e();}
```

Html Form

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" onsubmit="return formValidation()"  action="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use FormData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("subject", "value");
formData.append("message", "hello value");
```

This is the code that worked for me: (I think only difference is the url)

```
var url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
function do_ajax() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url + "?action=process_contact_form");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("subject", "value");
    formData.append("message", "hello value");
    request.send(formData);
}
```

and on the server:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_process_contact_form', 'process_contact_form');

function process_contact_form()
{
    echo $_POST["message"];
    die();
}
```

Comment: It worked! How can I retrieve volers from formData.append inside php function?

I tried with: $subject= $_POST['subject'];
But it did not work.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I forgot to send the formData `request.send(formData);`